# mean io swig block inside view

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, swig-template, angular-template

I'm using mean stack and have a problem with doing a basic thing like placing content in a block defined in the main layout.

What i have:

**MyProjectName/packages/core/system/server/views/layouts/default.html**

```
<div id="content-right" class="">
    {% block content-right %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

**MyProjectName/packages/custom/custompackagename/public/views/list.html**

```
{% block content-right %}
 Lorem ipsum
{% endblock %}
```

Instead of showing the content of "content-right" block (Lorem ipsum in this case) it shows the whole thing as a string, hence not working, the block is not rendered, not processed however mean works.

I found that **MyProjectName/packages/core/system/server/views/index.html** is used everywhere so if i place the block content snippet there it works. I dont want that because the stuff isnide the block should be according to the page where i am at, not same on every page. How do i achieve that? Its basic stuff, why would one .html file template render dynamic content as it should be and another is served like static...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering the same thing, here is what i've found

as per http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view we can create multiple named views inside our router file in MEAN IO stack that is **MyProjectName/packages/custom/custompackagename/public/routes/custompackage.js**

Here is an example of a state with two views

```
$stateProvider
      .state('all projects', {
          url: '/mypackage',
          views: {
              "" : {
                  templateUrl: '/mypackage/views/list.html'
              },
              "content-right" : {
                  templateUrl: '/mypackage/views/content-right.html'
              }
          }
  })
```

I've "declared" the position of my custom view inside the main layout file
**MyProjectName/packages/core/system/server/views/layouts/default.html**

```
<div id="content-right" class="">
    {% block content-right %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Then modify **MyProjectName/packages/core/system/server/views/index.html** to include the new named ui-view that we created inside the public router file

```
{% block content-right %}
<section data-ui-view="content-right"></section>
{% endblock %}
```

Then create the file specified inside the public router file for the view, in this case **/mypackage/views/content-right.html** had put your content there, refresh page, it works.